# How Do I Upload Product Images To Shopware 6 Via Admin

Tags: vue.js, shopware, shopware6

I am building a custom shopware 6 plugin to upload modified product images. How do I do it. I have checked Shopware Administration docs but I can only see documentation for `CRUD` operations only, there was no mention of media.

Comment: What do you mean with modified product images? Additional images in a special role, like currently is is possible with "set cover images" ? Or is the content of the image modified ? The images are managed via the media gallery - so this should be a good starting point.

Comment: DId you find a solution? Do you have more details?

Comment: No solution yet from Shopware 6 Administration, I used a walk around method using PHP to modify the product images. @Alex

Comment: "What do you mean with modified product images?" @Alex I was to upload the images via a custom Shopware 6 uploader and merge the image with specific product images.